# What is the best practice to develop the cross-platform components with Vue.js 2.0?

Tags: css, angularjs, reactjs, responsive-design, vue.js

I'm planning to write a common component library with Vue.js 2.0 and hope the library can work on multiple platforms. This question is about the best practices when it comes to a component's style.

On the PC / browser, We usually write CSS for fixed-width or flow layout with `px`. On a mobile platform (webview or browser), We usually write the CSS for flexible layout with `vw` / `rem`.

I see, some components only suit either one ( PC or mobile platform ), but still some components are common and versatility, such as Button, GridView, InputField and so on.

For example, there is a Button component that has a default padding style. In order to better adaptability, should I set the padding value by what unit? `px`? `rem`? For the goal, what is the best practice to do the things?

In fact, this question is not only related to Vue, but it's relevant for any frameworks that allows developing components, such as: React, Angular, Ember, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you stop thinking of browser / PC layout and mobile apps as being different. As it looks, you can't be sure what form factor's going to come next for both of them. That's true even for platforms that have been proven to be consistent, such as iPhone / iOS.

Responsive web design is the same in both environments, your layouts should be 'prepared' for a change in form factor.

Responsive web design is not different from React to Angular or anything in between. The only thing that differs is how CSS actually gets in your app.

No matter what you're designing for, you should:

> Respond to the needs of the users and the devices they're using. The layout changes based on the size and capabilities of the device.

The basic principles are: **Adapt, respond, and overcome**.

### Technical perspective

In Vue the way to go is: **isolate components, including styles -> use scoped styles whenever possible `<style scoped></style>`.**

Then (not specific to Vue), use fluid layouts however you want; some people choose **%**, some use **vh** / **vw** or **em** / **rem**. As long as it's fluid, you'll probably be fine. Many choose **vh** / **vw** for containers and use percentages afterwards, but there's no *default pattern*. With percentages, some people find it easier to mix in `calc()`, which can be a useful responsive tool.

Regarding your button example, it's probably a good idea to use `rem` or `em` as a default. However, for some components it might make sense to use `px` - don't be afraid to mix and match. This can save you a lot of code and there's no golden rule about it.

**Your breakpoints shouldn't be shaped after devices**, instead figure out where your content can be presented better. This way you'll build a more future-proof layout, which can turn out to be a nightmare to maintain.

Choose whatever makes you feel comfortable.
It's up to you to combine your tools and get the CSS to work for you / follow certain RWD patterns.

### Wrap up

That being said, [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/patterns) are some patterns you can follow when building your responsive apps:

- Mostly Fluid
- Column Drop
- Layout Shifter
- Tiny Tweaks
- Off Canvas

There's a [course](https://udacity.com/ud893) I encourage you to take if still in doubt.

In this course you'll learn the fundamentals of responsive web design with Google's Pete LePage! You'll create your own responsive web page that works well on any device - phone, tablet, desktop or anything in between. It might feel a bit slow in the beginning, but you'll learn a lot by the end of it.